# Cannot display bootstrap style sheets in Devise Sign in pages

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I'm using a template landing page to build my app off of. Inside the directory contains all the css files and style sheets which I'm referencing in my `application.html.erb` file. The issue occurs when connecting Devise for the profile & authentication component of my app we find the dependent css files are returning the error: `GET http://127.0.0.1:3001/users/landing%20page%20template/vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

My question is how can on one page load all the style sheets i.e header, footer etc when then trying to render the same tag produces these GET errors?
Help is apprecieated.
Below is the relevant code snippets..

If there is any other code components required please let me know. Thanks.

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JobFinder</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="landing page template/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="landing page template/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="landing page template/vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="landing page template/css/landing-page.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>

<main class='<%= controller.controller_name %>'>

  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
  <%= yield %>

  <footer>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="landing page template/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="landing page template/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </footer>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Devise form code:

```
<h2>Edit Profile
  <% resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>


  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %><br/>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br/>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <br/>
      <em><%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum</em>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br/>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br/>
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "current-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-secondary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<br/>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Cancel my account</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Unhappy?</h6>
    <p>
      <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete,
                    class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
    </p>
    <%= link_to "Back", :back %>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Console output errors]

Answer (score 1):

Why there are spaces in your directory ? remove them and replace it with underscore or a dash